# How to create a global shortcut using the Shortcuts app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, automation, shortcuts-app

Below is my current config using the Shortcuts app, although `Control-5` works in some apps, it still conflicts with the apps which use `Control-5`.

How to create a system-wide shortcut so that when it's sent, no other apps can capture that event?

[image]