# How to create shortcuts which only apply to a certain app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, automation, shortcuts-app

I want to map <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only when Chrome is active, in Windows, it's quite simple to implement by using AutoHotkey:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
  ^j::Send ^+{Tab}
  ^k::Send ^{Tab}
#IfWinActive
```

How to achieve this in the macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/):

```json
{
  "description": "Chrome Keybindings",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "type": "frontmost_application_if",
          "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.google\\.Chrome$"]
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "key_code": "j",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_command"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "tab",
          "modifiers": ["left_control", "left_shift"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "conditions": [
        {
          "type": "frontmost_application_if",
          "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.google\\.Chrome$"]
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "key_code": "k",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_command"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "tab",
          "modifiers": ["left_control"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is built into macOS.
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

The original Chrome Tab menu…

[image]

Click the + sign at the bottom, find your app in the list, add the exact name of the menu option you wish to change, then supply a new key command. The change is immediate on clicking Add.

[image]

The new command in place…

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, I knew the "App Shortcuts" exist, but I never expected it to work like that! However though, `Control-Tab/Control-Shift-Tab` no longer works, is there any way to let both `Control-Tab/Control-Shift-Tab` and `Command-J/Command-K` coexist?

Comment: Could you please also take a look at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/450300/424683) as well, if it could be done by using the Shortcuts app, I'll uninstall the third-party tool for doing this.

Comment: The only way to have two shortcuts is if one is undocumented, therefore not changed by the command. For browsers, inc Chrome, the undocumented one Is Cmd/shift/ [ or ]. I've no idea how the shortcuts app works, never used it.

Comment: Thanks, how do you find `Cmd/shift/ [ or ]` if it's not documented :O?

Comment: They're the default key commands in Mac generally, eg Finder, Safari etc - they just happen to work in Chrome too.

Comment: I'm curious what does `Cmd/shift/ [ or ]` do in the Finder? I've tried it several times, seems like nothing's happening.

Comment: Just the same - next or previous tab. You need to be using tabs, of course.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, are these app shortcuts synced between macbooks using the same Apple ID? If not, is there any way to achieve this?